# kafka streams - Restore state store infinite loop with EOS and enable.idempotence=true

Tags: infinite-loop, apache-kafka-streams, eos

Switched on EOS (KS 1.1.0)
On a clean local env, all topics with 2 partitions.
produceing few messages using ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG=true

after restarting the app, the global state store restore goes into infinite loop.

implemented StateRestoreListener and added logs to onRestoreStart, onRestoreEnd, onBatchRestored

here is what I see in the log repeatedly: (topic name is bu)

```
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,590 | org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=bu) to node jonathan:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,591 | org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata | Updated cluster metadata version 3 to Cluster(id = Kw31wtS9TYm__QEmSUDgdg, nodes = [jonathan:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = bu, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = bu, partition = 1, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = [])])
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,592 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Sending ListOffsetRequest (type=ListOffsetRequest, replicaId=-1, partitionTimestamps={bu-1=-1, bu-0=-1}, isolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED) to broker jonathan:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,595 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Handling ListOffsetResponse response for bu-1. Fetched offset 12, timestamp -1
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,596 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Handling ListOffsetResponse response for bu-0. Fetched offset 16, timestamp -1
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,596 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Subscribed to partition(s): bu-1
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,596 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Seeking to offset 9 for partition bu-1


{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:START] bu bu-1, startingOffset:9","endOfBatch":false}


DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,640 | org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics | Added sensor with name topic.bu.bytes-fetched
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,642 | org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics | Added sensor with name topic.bu.records-fetched
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,642 | org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics | Added sensor with name bu-1.records-lag
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,643 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Added READ_COMMITTED fetch request for partition bu-1 at offset 12 to node jonathan:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,643 | org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=1036463678, epoch=1) for node 0. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,643 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Sending READ_COMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(bu-1), toForget=(), implied=()) to broker jonathan:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)

{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:BATCH] bu bu-1, batchEndOffset:12","endOfBatch":false}
{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:END] bu bu-1, totalRestored:1","endOfBatch":false}


DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,649 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Subscribed to partition(s): bu-0
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,649 | org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics | Removed sensor with name bu-1.records-lag
DEBUG | AppName-GlobalStreamThread | 2018-06-17 20:07:21,649 | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=AppName-global-restore-consumer, groupId=] Seeking to offset 15 for partition bu-0

{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:START] bu bu-0, startingOffset:15","endOfBatch":false}
{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:BATCH] bu bu-0, batchEndOffset:15","endOfBatch":false}
{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:BATCH] bu bu-0, batchEndOffset:15","endOfBatch":false}
{"thread":"AppName-GlobalStreamThread","message":"[RESTORE:BATCH] bu bu-0, batchEndOffset:15","endOfBatch":false}
...
...
```

repeatedly
I could not find a known issue related to EOS and global state store,
anyone seen this?

Comment: You might hit: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6782 ? Kafka community it preparing an AK 1.1.1 bug-fix release atm: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Release+Plan+1.1.1

Comment: Thanks Matthias, working around this for now by separating apps and making sure I am not producing messages into global table backing topics with EOS enabled

Answer (score 1):

Found this related issue:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201711.mbox/%3CCAG53Ff=H8e_DeAKq7BOz_LdMtf2wD_SETM9PBonwZyBNJ2HZ3w@mail.gmail.com%3E

for now, I am not enabling EOS for apps that produce records into topics that are backing global tables. This solves the infinite loop upon global table restore.

Comment: That's the report that resulted in KAFKA-6782.